# Arabic Or Persian Digists In SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

i am using SQL Server Reporting Service in my asp.net application.
I am converting reports to pdf to show to user.
numbers are English.
how can i use arabic or persian Numbers instead English Numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to control this by formatting your report (including numeric values) to use the culture defined by the version of Windows your users are using. Don't specifically provide a format string. Let Windows format your numerics based on the culture setting.